# Inline function in namespace gives undefined reference to, C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, inline

I have a very simple program in which I define my own namespace and need to have an inline function. This looks like this one below:

**test.h**

```
#ifndef _TEST_H_
#define _TEST_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace NS
{

class EXAMPLE
{
    int i;
    float f;

public:

    void doSth();
};
}

#endif
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"

namespace NS
{
inline void EXAMPLE::doSth()
{
    cout << i << f << "\n";
}
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    NS::EXAMPLE e;

    e.doSth();

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it like this: `g++ main.cpp test.cpp -o app` which results in

```
/tmp/ccFwG8do.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `NS::EXAMPLE::doSth()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want it to be inline, the implementation has to be in the *header* and it needs to be declared inline there. Otherwise there's no way for the compiler to inline it in other compilation units, since it can't see the details.

Comment: Note: `_TEST_H_` is a reserved name.

Comment: Note: `using namespace std;` should **never** be used in the global namespace in a header. E.g. code that uses the name `distance` and includes that header, can get a name collision. Ungood.

Comment: Note: the all uppercase names `NS` and `EXAMPLE` are likely to collide with macro names, cause unintended and undesirable text substitution. The common convention to avoid that is, use all uppercase names for all macros, and for macros only.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts if I move my arm this way." "Well, don't move your arm that way, then."

Comment: I'm pretty sure `inline` functions need to be declared as being `inline` at the point of use.

Comment: Note: you do not need a `return 0;` in `main`, since it's the default for `main`.

Comment: Finally, note: `<iostream>` is a "heavy" header, so you'd want to not include that in your own header, because it forces the inclusion on client code. In  your concrete example you can simply move that include to the .cpp implementation file. More generally, where you need to refer to e.g. `std::istream` in a header you can instead include **`<iosfwd>`** in the header, and do the full include of `<iostream>` in the implementation file. This is the only such forward declarations header in the standard library. And it's there because `<iostream>` is so heavy that one generally wants to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

An `inline` function must be defined as `inline` in all translation units where it's used, with the same definition.

Essentially that means either (1) using it in only one translation unit, or (2) placing the definition in a header that's included in every translation unit where the function's used.

The use case (1) is where one desires the *hinting effect* of `inline`, that it directs the compiler to consider whether to inline calls to the function, in the generated machine code. Use case (2) is about the *guarantee* provided by `inline`, that such use in multiple translation units is not a violation of the One Definition Rule (or ODR, as it's often referred to).